# binaries not executable by user (Permission denied) after cmake install / make install to /usr/local/bin

Tags: permissions, make, cmake

After I install any project on my Debian (Buster) machine with `sudo cmake install` or `sudo make install` command, the binary gets placed inside `/usr/local/bin` but although the PATH variable is set correctly and even after a reboot, bash or fish cant find the command for the binaries installed that way.

This happened with `cmake` and `nvim` so far. For `nvim`, for example, I followed the build from source instructions:

1. cloned repo with git
2. make CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
3. sudo make install

Now if I run `nvim`, the command is not found, but if I run `sudo nvim` the binary is started correctly.

I compared the file permissions of binaries that are perfectly executable without sudo rights inside `/usr/bin` and they are exactly the same permissions as the binaries inside `/usr/local/bin`.

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root     root`.

What am I doing wrong, and why are the binaries inside `/usr/bin` executable without sudo and files installed from source inside `/usr/local/bin` not?

This is my PATH variable:
`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games`

Additional info:
If I run: `/usr/local/bin/nvim` this is the output:
`fish: The file “/usr/local/bin/nvim” is not executable by this user`

If I run `type -a nvim` the output is:
`type: Could not find 'nvim'`

if I run `sudo ./pathlld /usr/local/bin/nvim` I get the following output:

```
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root 4096 Dec 22 12:17 /
/dev/nvme0n1p2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime)
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096 May  5 13:19 /usr
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Mar 24 15:51 /usr/local
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 May  5 14:21 /usr/local/bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10319072 May  5 14:21 /usr/local/bin/nvim
```

I'm running a custom OS by the company Siemens that is called "Siemens Industrial OS"; it is basically a Debian Buster with a realtime-patch.

Comment: Instead of showing only parts of the information, please run the commands `ls -l /usr/local/bin/nvim*` and `type /usr/local/bin/nvim*` and copy&paste the commands and their output. What is your OS? Which version of `fish` do you use? Maybe this is related: https://superuser.com/q/1270908/992527

Comment: @Bodo the OS is Debian, mentioned in the first sentence.

Comment: Is it possible that /usr/local is on a separate filesystem, that is mounted with the `noexec` option?

Comment: @steeldriver shouldn't this affect the root user also?

Comment: @thanasisp oops I missed that part ... although it's not actually stated that `sudo /usr/local/bin/nvim` works, only that `sudo nvim` does (so I guess it's possible that there's a different `nvim` somewhere on sudo's `secure_path`)

Comment: @thanasisp I dont have any other version than the one installed with make. If doesnt matter if I run sudo nvim OR sudo /usr/local/bin/nvim both ways work. its just when I doesnt run with sudo that the command is not found or permission errors occurr. My Fish version is 3.4.1 my bash is 5.0.3. it happens with both equally so it doesnt matter.

Comment: @Bodo unfortunatelly your commands doesnt change anything the type command cant find nvim and the ls command olnly shows the permissions that I already postet with the question.

Comment: @steeldriver how can I test if this is the case?

Comment: You could use something like `findmnt -T /usr/local/bin` or examine the output of the `mount` command (`mount | grep local` for example). But if `sudo /usr/local/bin/nvim` works, then `noexec` is likely not the explanation here.

Comment: Are you running `selinux, `apparmor` or other such security module?

Comment: Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`, a `bash` script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.

Comment: @waltinator thank you I've added the output to my question above.

Comment: @Bib I search processes like selinux and apparmor with htop and cant find any processes named like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 May  5 14:21 /usr/local/bin
```

group and others have no execute and read permission on `/usr/local/bin`. Run as root:

```
chmod 755 /usr/local/bin
```

to restore the standard permissions for this directory.

Comment: Thank you so much this solved it! Do you know why this path was set like this by default? I have two systems that I set up the same way with the same OS from Siemens that I did not change permissions to that path this was by default!?

Comment: I don't know the reasons for a specific OS to do it. I don't think that a common Linux distribution would set it like this as default, this directory should be executable for others by default.